# FastAPI Endpoint Returning Empty Data

Tags: python-3.x, function, fastapi, web-development-server

I am working on a FastAPI endpoint (/all) that is supposed to fetch data from a database and return it in response. However, I am encountering an issue where the response data is very less compared to the amount stored in the database(Leads in the database area around 59799 but the Swagger UI only provides an output of 1209 Leads), and I can't figure out why.
PS I tried to troubleshoot problem hence have commented a bunch of code.
This  block may resolve the issue but Pagination is being disabled.

```
# query = text(query)
# x = print("SQL Query:", query)
# result = db.get_db().execute(query)
# columns = result.keys()  # Get the column names
# data = [dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in result.fetchall()]
```

```
@router.post("/all", operation_id="get_all_leads")
def get_all_leads(
    paging: paging = None,
    assigned: int | None = None,
    source: int | None = None,
    status: str | None = None,
    additional_filters: int | None = None,
    username: User = Depends(get_current_account),
    customer_id: Annotated[str | None, Header()] = None
):
    '''
    This api gets all the leads 
    
    parameters
    -------
    
    - filter text -> the text you want to search for 
    - limit_per_page -> the amount of data that should be fetched in a single page 
    - order by -> order the data by the column name  
    - skip -> skips the data (eg : 0,10,20,30)
    - sort -> sort the column (1 : asc , -1 : desc)  
    
    filters 
    -------
    
    - assigned : id of assigned staff
    - source  : source id 
    - status : csv of status id (eg : 1,7,4,3)
    - additional_filters : addition filter for the DataTable
    '''
    try:
        if paging is None:
            paging = paging()
        
        db = LoadDatabase(customer_id)

        filters = {'assigned': assigned,
                'source': source,
                "status": status,
                "additional_filters": additional_filters
                }

        query = fetch_leads_all(db.get_db(), single_lead=None, filters=filters)
        # query = text(query)
        # x = print("SQL Query:", query)
        # result = db.get_db().execute(query)
        # columns = result.keys()  # Get the column names
        # data = [dict(zip(columns, row)) for row in result.fetchall()]  # Convert rows to dictionaries
        paging_params = df_datatables(dataframe=None,
                                    sql=query,
                                    db_connection=db.get_engine(),
                                    params={
                                        'paging':paging,
                                        'filter': paging.filter_text,
                                        'order_by': paging.order_by,
                                        'sort_asc': assign_order(paging.sort),
                                        'skip': paging.skip,
                                        'limit_per_page': paging.limit_per_page,
                                        "exclude_column_search": []
                                    }
                                    )

        data = []  # Initialize the data variable as an empty list
        #output = paging_params.get_data()
        data = output["dataframe"].to_dict(orient="records")

        return {
            "status": "success",
            "total_record": output["total_record"],
            "data": data
        }

    except HTTPException as e:
        raise e
```

Comment: Have you tested using cURL or a similar tool? The Swagger UI is not great at handling large amounts of data.

Comment: Also start by looking at what data your API is actually returning in a debugger - set a breakpoint at the start and confirm that you're actually fetching and returning as many rows as you think you are - narrow down the possible locations where the error is introduced

Comment: I tried cURL too but that did not work, got same result. Replying to M.O.

Comment: I did not understood how to do that @MatsLindh